# for loop not working in bash

Tags: bash, for

i have the below code to replace some strigns in multiple files, but the for loop is checking for the first file and not executing the perl script. below is my code

```
if [ -f zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD.v ]
then
    for file in $(./zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD*);
    do
    perl -i -p -e 's/input/inout/g' $file; 
        perl -i -p -e 's/output/inout/g' $file;
        perl -i -p -e 's/wire.*\n/tran\(i0,\ o\);/g' $file;
        perl -i -p -e 's/assign.*\n//g' $file;
    done
fi
```

Comment: Remove the `$(...)` around your filename globbing pattern. You don't need a command substitution there. You may also combine the four Perl invocations to a single one for speed.

Answer (score 10):

The `$(foo)` construct will run the command `foo` and replace `$(foo)` with the output of running `foo`. You want a glob, that's not a command. What you're doing is attempting to run all files called `./zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD*`. All you need is:

```
if [ -f zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD.v ]
then
    for file in ./zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD*;
    do
        perl -i -p -e 's/input/inout/g' "$file"
        perl -i -p -e 's/output/inout/g' "$file"
        perl -i -p -e 's/wire.*\n/tran\(i0,\ o\);/g' "$file"
        perl -i -p -e 's/assign.*\n//g' "$file"
    done
fi
```

Or, more simply:

```
if [ -f zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD.v ]
then
    for file in ./zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD*;
    do
        perl -i -p -e 's/input/inout/g; s/output/inout/g; 
                       s/wire.*\n/tran\(i0,\ o\);/g; 
                       s/assign.*\n//g' "$file"
    done
fi
```

Or even more simply:

```
if [ -f zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD.v ]
then
    perl -i -p -e 's/input/inout/g; s/output/inout/g; 
                   s/wire.*\n/tran\(i0,\ o\);/g; 
                   s/assign.*\n//g' ./zebu.work.post_opt/ZEBU_CTO_FT_MOD*
fi
```

Comment: Is the loop even needed? Can `perl -ip` work on several files at once? I've never tested taht.

Comment: @Kusalananda indeed it can. Should have thought of that, thanks!